# trying to write data in text file

Tags: jsp

> i have created a bean class named **User**; its working fine , as its working for setter and getter properties
>   and a class **UserIO** as below

```
public class UserIO {
public static void add(User user, String filepath) throws IOException{
File file =new File(filepath);
out.println(user.getEmailAddress()+ " | " +user.getFirstName() + " | " +user.getLastName());
out.close();}}
```

> finally i am calling it from a jsp file as below:

```
<% String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName"); 
   String lastName = request.getParameter("lasttName");
   String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");

   ServletContext sc=this.getServletContext();
   String path =sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");

    User user = new User(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);
    UserIO.add(user, path);

   <%= user.getFirstName() %>
```

> The program is running fine, without any exception. User class is also working, as i can set and get values. But, the data is not being written in the EmailList.txt file(which is in web-inf dir, its path is showing correct when i m using RealPath). I am using Netbeans IDE. Can anyone help me to solve it. 
>   moreover in UserIO class i have also tried below code(its not working either:

```
 FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(filepath, true);
fos.write((user.getEmailAddress()+ " | " + user.getFirstName() + " | " + user.getLastName()).getBytes());
```

Comment: tried both closing and non-closing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE PROBLEM
what i was doing was- created a text file named EmailList.txt inside the NetBeans web-inf dir.
But the code generates and creates a txt file inside the projects 'build\web\WEB-INF\' directory. And writes the data.
Moreover, Both the code works....
:-)